# virtualenvwrapper: mkvirtualenv works but rmvirtualenv returns -bash: no such file or directory

Tags: python, virtualenvwrapper

I was following this tutorial to learn how to configure python/pip/virtualenvwrapper on my MacOSX Yosemite 10.10.5

http://www.lecloud.net/post/119427148455/python-pip-on-mac-os-x-yosemite

Now I create a test folder: "~/PythonProj"

"mkvirtualenv" just works if I type mkvirtualenv test1 in "Terminal.app"

```
mkvirtualenv test1
```

other commands also works fine, like:

```
workon test1
deactivate test1
```

while, strange thing happens when I want to delete "test1"

```
rmvirtualenv test1
```

failure message is like:

```
-bash: cd: ~/.virtualenvs: No such file or directory
```

I then visit ~/.virtualenvs and end up finding no "test1" folder.

My question:

1) when I type "mkvirtualenv test1", **where is the "test1" folder stored?**  since i could not find it in "~/PythonProj" or "~/.virtualenvs"

2) **Is there something wrong with my configuration** ? is it a permission problem?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directory should be saved to your .virtualenvs folder just like you said.

During installation you should have setup an environment variable for WORKON_HOME. You can check to see if it is set correctly by typing this in your terminal:

```
echo $WORKON_HOME
```

If you do not see anything returned, check your ~/.profile file to see if it is set to the correct directory. There should be an entry that looks like this:

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
```

Comment: thanks @TheGRS   It turned out that my configuration is not proper.

Comment: originally in the file ~/.profile  'export WORKON_HOME... ' should be put before 'source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh', but in my previous file, I mistake the order, so that 'export WORKON_HOME' is not executed